# How do I find the limit $\lim_{z\to i}\frac{\sqrt[3]{z + i} - \sqrt[3]{2i}}{\sqrt{z} - \sqrt{i}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

[find the limit of a function of complex variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFcCd.jpg)

I need to find the following limit of a function of complex variable:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\to i}\frac{\sqrt[3]{z + i} - \sqrt[3]{2i}}{\sqrt{z} - \sqrt{i}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Hello @Átila, I don't know how I could solve the exercise, since I don't know how to solve the limits with complex variable. If you could help me or guide me to solve it that would be great.  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE @Oriana. Try to apply the identity:

$$x^{3} - y^{3} = (x - y)(x^{2} + xy + y^{2})$$

If you cannot make progress, tell me so that I can better help you.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try to solve it using that identity, I'll let you know if I still can't solve it @Átila

Comment: Hint: this is a derivative.

Comment: L'Hopital?${}{}{}$

Comment: multiply and divide by $z-i$. then look for expressions that look like derivatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a computation of
the principal value.
There are
6 possible values of
the square and cube roots,
but I'll let myself be bashed
for ignoring them.

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{z\to i}\frac{\sqrt[3]{z + i} - \sqrt[3]{2i}}{\sqrt{z} - \sqrt{i}}
&=\lim_{w+i\to i}\frac{\sqrt[3]{w+i + i} - \sqrt[3]{2i}}{\sqrt{w+i} - \sqrt{i}}\\
&=\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{w+2i} - \sqrt[3]{2i}}{\sqrt{w+i} - \sqrt{i}}\\
&=\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{2i}\sqrt[3]{1+w/\sqrt[3]{2i}} - \sqrt[3]{2i}}{ \sqrt{i}\sqrt{1+w/ \sqrt{i}} - \sqrt{i}}\\
&=\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{2i}(\sqrt[3]{1+w/\sqrt[3]{2i}} - 1)}{ \sqrt{i}(\sqrt{1+w/ \sqrt{i}} - 1)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt[3]{2i}}{\sqrt{i}}\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{1+w/(3\sqrt[3]{2i})+O(w^2) - 1}{ 1+w/(2 \sqrt{i})+O(w^2) - 1)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt[3]{2i}}{\sqrt{i}}\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{w/(3\sqrt[3]{2i})+O(w^2)}{w/(2 \sqrt{i})+O(w^2)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt[3]{2i}}{\sqrt{i}}\lim_{w\to 0}(\frac{2 \sqrt{i}}{3\sqrt[3]{2i}}+O(w))\\
&=\frac23\\
\end{array}
$